# Having a bit of trouble with a JScrollPane

Tags: java, swing, jscrollpane

I'm trying to make a scrollable JTextArea. I'm not quite sure what's wrong with my code here... When I create this GUI, it doesn't create the `chatBox`

```
package GUI;

import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.awt.event.KeyEvent;
import java.awt.event.KeyListener;
import java.awt.event.WindowAdapter;
import java.awt.event.WindowEvent;

import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JMenu;
import javax.swing.JMenuBar;
import javax.swing.JMenuItem;
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JScrollPane;
import javax.swing.JTextArea;
import javax.swing.JTextField;
import javax.swing.border.EmptyBorder;

import Client.Client;

@SuppressWarnings("serial")
public class GUI extends JFrame implements KeyListener {

    public static JPanel contentPane;
    public static JTextField usernameBox;
    public static JTextField inputBox;
    public static JTextField ipBox;
    public static JLabel usernameLabel;
    public static JButton connectButton;
    public static JButton disconnectButton;
    public static JLabel usersLabel;
    public static JTextArea usersBox;
    public static JTextArea chatBox;
    public static JButton sendButton;
    public static JLabel ipLabel;
    public static JMenuBar menuBar;
    public static JMenu file;
    public static JMenuItem about;
    public static JMenuItem connect;
    public static JMenuItem disconnect;
    public static JMenuItem setDefaultUsername;
    public static JMenuItem setDefaultIP;
    public static String setUser;
    public static String setIP;
    public static String title;
    public static JScrollPane scroll = new JScrollPane(chatBox);

    @SuppressWarnings("unused")
    private static About aboutFrame;

    public GUI() {
        System.out.println("Creating new client...");
        addItems();
        System.out.println("DONE");
    }

    public void addItems() {
        // Frame
        title = "title";
        setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        setBounds(100, 100, 760, 355);
        setTitle(title);
        setSize(770, 385);
        setResizable(false);
        // Panel
        contentPane = new JPanel();
        contentPane.setBorder(new EmptyBorder(5, 5, 5, 5));
        contentPane.setLayout(null);
        // Username Box
        usernameBox = new JTextField();
        usernameBox.setBounds(88, 6, 117, 28);
        usernameBox.setColumns(10);
        contentPane.add(usernameBox);
        // Username Label
        usernameLabel = new JLabel("Username");
        usernameLabel.setBounds(17, 12, 72, 16);
        contentPane.add(usernameLabel);
        // Connect Button
        connectButton = new JButton("Connect");
        connectButton.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                System.out.println("Connect");
                Client.Connect();
            }
        });
        connectButton.setBounds(365, 7, 117, 29);
        contentPane.add(connectButton);
        // Disconnect Button
        disconnectButton = new JButton("Disconnect");
        disconnectButton.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                System.out.println("Disconnect");
                Client.Disconnect();
            }
        });
        disconnectButton.setBounds(493, 7, 117, 29);
        contentPane.add(disconnectButton);
        // Users Label
        usersLabel = new JLabel("Users");
        usersLabel.setBounds(664, 12, 61, 16);
        contentPane.add(usersLabel);
        // Users Box
        usersBox = new JTextArea();
        usersBox.setEditable(false);
        usersBox.setBounds(622, 40, 122, 282);
        contentPane.add(usersBox);
        // Chat Box
        chatBox = new JTextArea();
        chatBox.setEditable(false);
        chatBox.setBounds(17, 40, 593, 226);
        scroll = new JScrollPane(chatBox, JScrollPane.VERTICAL_SCROLLBAR_ALWAYS, JScrollPane.HORIZONTAL_SCROLLBAR_ALWAYS);
        contentPane.add(scroll);
        // Input Box
        inputBox = new JTextField();
        inputBox.setBounds(17, 274, 506, 48);
        contentPane.add(inputBox);
        inputBox.setColumns(10);
        inputBox.addKeyListener(this);
        inputBox.setEditable(false);
        // Send Button
        sendButton = new JButton("Send");
        sendButton.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                System.out.println("Send");
                Client.Send();
            }
        });
        sendButton.setBounds(526, 274, 84, 48);
        contentPane.add(sendButton);
        // ipLabel
        ipLabel = new JLabel("IP");
        ipLabel.setBounds(215, 12, 17, 16);
        contentPane.add(ipLabel);
        // ipBox
        ipBox = new JTextField();
        ipBox.setBounds(236, 6, 117, 28);
        contentPane.add(ipBox);
        ipBox.setColumns(10);
        // Set Pane
        setContentPane(contentPane);
        // send disconnect on close of window
        addWindowListener(new WindowAdapter() {
            public void windowClosing(WindowEvent e) {
                Client.Disconnect();
            }
        });
        menuBar = new JMenuBar();
        setJMenuBar(menuBar);
        file = new JMenu("File");
        menuBar.add(file);
        about = new JMenuItem("About");
        file.add(about);
        connect = new JMenuItem("Connect");
        file.add(connect);
        disconnect = new JMenuItem("Disconnect");
        file.add(disconnect);
        setDefaultUsername = new JMenuItem("Set default username.");
        file.add(setDefaultUsername);
        setDefaultIP = new JMenuItem("Set default IP address.");
        file.add(setDefaultIP);
        about.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent ae) {
                aboutFrame = new About();
            }
        });
        setDefaultUsername.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent ae) {
                promptDefaultUser();
            }
        });
        setDefaultIP.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent ae) {
                promptDefaultIP();
            }
        });
        connect.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                Client.Connect();
            }
        });
        disconnect.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                Client.Disconnect();
            }
        });
    }

    public void keyPressed(KeyEvent e) {
        if (e.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.VK_ENTER)
            Client.Send();
    }

    public void keyReleased(KeyEvent e) {

    }

    public void keyTyped(KeyEvent e) {

    }
}
```

Comment: You shall not add multiple times the same element. Create `chatBox`, create `scroll` with `chatBox` in it, and add `scroll` to `contentPane` only one time.

Comment: Whoops. Even with that change, I still don't get the chatBox drawn to the pane.

Comment: Also: when I leave out the JScrollPane, the chatBox appears.

Comment: try creating the scrollpane with the chatbox after the chatbox is created.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to place the JTextArea and the JScrollPane at the right places, then everything should work.

- The JTextArea resides inside the JScrollPane and it is not required to call `setBounds(...)` on it. This is because the origin of the JTextArea inside the scrollpane should be (0,0).
- The JScrollPane needs to be placed at the location where you placed the JTextArea at.

  ```
  chatBox = new JTextArea();   
  chatBox.setEditable(false);    

  scroll = new JScrollPane(chatBox, JScrollPane.VERTICAL_SCROLLBAR_ALWAYS, JScrollPane.HORIZONTAL_SCROLLBAR_ALWAYS);
  scroll.setBounds(17,40,593,226);
  contentPane.add(scroll);
  ```

Answer (score 1):

**Don't use a null layout!!!**

Your scrollpane doesn't have a proper size so its not painted. Even if it does get painted. Swing was designed to be used with layout managers for too many reasons to list here.

Read the JTextArea API and follow the link to the Swing tutorial where you will find working examples of the proper way to use a text area in a scrollpane.

Answer (score 0):

```
chatBox = new JTextArea();
        chatBox.setEditable(false);
        chatBox.setBounds(17, 40, 593, 226);
        scroll = new JScrollPane(chatBox, JScrollPane.VERTICAL_SCROLLBAR_ALWAYS, JScrollPane.HORIZONTAL_SCROLLBAR_ALWAYS);
        contentPane.add(scroll);
        // Input Box
```

**issues**:

1. where are you setting the Bound of `JSCrollPane` to become visible in the panel with `null layout`?
2. You are using null layout! you should use `LayoutManager` which will lay out your GUI component for you. start learning them.
3. JScrollPane uses the component's preferred size under it's view to scroll it. Well don't rush to set the preferred size of chatBox right now. The `LayoutManager` should do it for you.

start learning from : [A Visual Guide to Layout Managers](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/visual.html)